# python classes dependant on eachother, how to init?

Tags: python

I have two classes:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, b):
    self b = b

class B(object):
  def __init__(self, a):
    self a = a
```

I'd like to init them like this:

```
a = A(b)
b = B(a)
```

But I can't since 'b' doesn't exist when doing `a = A(b)`. I have to do:

```
a = A()
b = B(a)
b.a = a
```

But that seems unclean. Is this solvable?

Comment: Do you really need to assign the references during initialization?  How about assigning them after creating the instances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could either make one class instantiate the other:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.b = B(self)

class B(object):
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a

a = A()
b = a.b
```

Or make one class tell the other about itself, like this:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, b):
    self.b = b
    b.a = self

class B(object):
  def __init__(self):
    #Will be set by A later
    self.a = None

b = B()
a = A(b)
```